# Number of one dimensional subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a three dimensional vector space over $\mathbb Z_3$. Then the problem is to count the distinct one dimensional subspaces. $\mathbb R^3 $ has infinitely many one dimensional subspaces. If $v_1, v_2, v_3$ are a basis, any nontrivial linear combination of these three vectors leads to a one dimensional subspace. How to isolate the distinct ones?

Answer (score 7):

**Hint:** How many non-zero vectors are there? When do two non-zero vectors determine the same subspace?

**Remark:** In general, take a finite field $F$ with $k$ elements, and look at the one-dimensional subspaces of an $n$-dimensional space over $F$. Then there are $k^n-1$ non-zero vectors. For any vector $v$, there are $k-1$ vectors that determine the same subspace as $v$ (multiply $v$ by any non-zero element). So the number of one-dimensional subspaces is $\frac{k^n-1}{k-1}$.  We can extend this analysis to count the $d$-dimensional subspaces.

Comment: There will be 26 non zero vectors. Two non zero vectors will span the same subspace if they are scalar multiples of each other. Then....?

Comment: So the number is $26/2$.

Comment: sorry! how we conclude this?

Comment: If you want to be fancy, call two non-zero vectors equivalent if they determine the same subspace. You are aware that each equivalence class ("family") has $2$ people in it. We have $26$ people, $2$ people per family, so $13$ families.

Comment: there are only two non-zero scalars in $\mathbb{Z}_3$, namely $1$ and $2$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thanks for your detailed answer

Comment: You are welcome. I have added a remark about generalization.

Answer (score 0):

For the detailed discussion of Quasi Binomial Co-efficients : http://arxiv.org/abs/1006.2193